# How can I make my Wordpress website protected from guest visitors

Tags: wordpress, authentication, web

How can I make my website protected from guest visitors, and give them access to the site after login in WordPress???

Comment: You could use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ and check the box for "private site"

Comment: I already have RH BuddyPress Member Types installed  on my site, but it not helps

Comment: We use the plugin in my link all the time for development environments. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You could write this in the functions.php of your theme:

```php
    /**
     * Enables Frontend Login
     */
    function enableFrontendLoginFn()
    {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            auth_redirect();
        }
    }

    add_action('template_redirect', 'enableFrontendLoginFn');
```

Then you must log in before you can see the page